# How to exclude generation of .txt4 files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4

I use T4 to generate some SQL files in a different project (but in the same solution). But it also  generates an empty txt4 file.
Are they essential to the generation of the SQL files?
Is there a way to stop them from generating?
I hope the picture brings some clarity.

[image: overview from my Solution Explorer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I found an answer.
I found it on this [site](https://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/forum/forum.aspx?g=posts&t=289)
This is a solution for T4 version 2.1

**The solution:**
You need to change 1 line of code at Line 457:

```
EnvDTE.ProjectItem pi = VSHelper.GetTemplateProjectItem(templateProjectItem.DTE, item.FirstItem, templateProjectItem);
```

to:

```
EnvDTE.Project prj = VSHelper.GetProject(dte, item.ProjectName);
EnvDTE.ProjectItem pi = VSHelper.GetAllProjectItemsRecursive(prj.ProjectItems).Where(i=>i.Name == item.FolderName).First();
```

But this change makes that it deletes all existing files when u generate T4.